# How do I implement the Structure tensor (in Matlab)?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, software-implementation

I am trying to figure out the details on how to implement the structure tensor in Matlab and need some advice!

For an image $\ I(x,y) $ the structure tensor S is given by:

$$ S=\begin{pmatrix}
W \ast I_x^2 & W \ast (I_xI_y)\\
W \ast (I_xI_y) & W \ast I_y^2  
\end{pmatrix}$$
where W is a smoothing kernel, $\ \ast $ denotes convolution and subscript denotes partial derivative with respect to.

I want to use a Gaussian as smoothing kernel. This is separable:
$$ W = G_{\sigma}*(G_{\sigma})^T$$
The constant $\ \sigma $ controls the outer/integration scale.
E.g. if I truncate it at $\ +/- 2\sigma$ and use  $\ \sigma = 1$ I get:

$$ G_{\sigma} = [0.0103,0.2076,0.5642,0.2076,0.0103] $$

However the input to the Gaussian might have a mean different from 0.

**How do I compensate for this?**

I was thinking substracting the mean first.

I could use central differences to estimate the partial derivatives:
$$ I_x \approx [-0.5 \hspace{2 pt} 0 \hspace{2 pt} 0.5]*I $$ 
However since the image is noisy it is probably better to use a more robust differentian operator.
The Sobel operator is such an operator. However according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) it is not perfectly rotational symmetric. The Scharr operators are supposed to be perfectly rotational symmetric and robust approximations of the partial derivatives:

$$ I_x \approx \frac{1}{32}\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 0 & 3\\
-10 & 0 & 10\\
-3 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix} * I$$

$$ I_y \approx \frac{1}{32}\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & -10 & -3\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 10 & 3
\end{pmatrix} * I$$

The Scharr operators are separable:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 0 & 3\\
-10 & 0 & 10\\
-3 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix} = [-1,0,1]*[3,10,3]^T $$

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
-3 & -10 & -3\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 10 & 3
\end{pmatrix} = [3,10,3]*[-1,0,1]^T$$

The elements of the structure tensor now becomes series of consecutive horizontal and vertical convolutions with the original image.

EDIT: Another option (thanks to nikie!) is the Gaussian derivative.
Introducing 
$$ GD_{\sigma}=\frac{-x}{\sigma}G{\sigma}$$

**Is this then correct?**
$$ Ix = G{\sigma}^T*(GD_{\sigma}*I) $$
$$ Iy = G{\sigma}*(GD_{\sigma}^T*I) $$

**How do I Implement this easily in Matlab?**

**How about in C++?**

**Any comments regarding choice of smoothing kernel and differentiation operator?**

EDIT 2: My Matlab code so far:

```
% I: image
% si: inner (differetiation) scale,
% so: outer (integration) scale
function [Sxx, Sxy, Syy] = structureTensor(I,si,so)
[m n] = size(I);

Sxx = NaN(m,n);
Sxy = NaN(m,n);
Syy = NaN(m,n);

% Robust differentiation by convolution with derivative of Gaussian:
x  = -2*si:2*si;
g  = exp(-0.5*(x/si).^2);
g  = g/sum(g);
gd = -x.*g/si; % is this normalized?

Ix = conv2( g',conv2(gd,I) );
Iy = conv2( g,conv2(gd',I) );

Ixx = Ix.^2;
Ixy = Ix.*Iy;
Iyy = Iy.^2;


% Smoothing:
x  = -2*so:2*so;
g  = exp(-0.5*(x/so).^2);
Sxx = conv2( g',conv2(g,Ixx) ); 
Sxy = conv2( g',conv2(g,Ixy) );
Syy = conv2( g',conv2(g,Iyy) );
```

**How do I normalize the Gaussian derivative?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However the input to the Gaussian might have a mean different from 0.

Unless your image is completely constant, $I_x^2$ and $I_y^2$ are guaranteed to have a mean > 0 (assuming the input pixels are all reals, of course).

> How do I compensate for this?

Why would you want to do that?

> I was thinking substracting the mean first.

Subtracting the mean before applying a derivative operator like Sobel or Scharr? That shouldn't make any difference.

> The Scharr operators are supposed to be perfectly rotational symmetric

Perfect rotational symmetry? Is that even possible with a finite kernel? I think the Scharr operator is just optimal (in a least-squares sense) for that filter size. With larger filter sizes, you get better rotational symmetry.

> How do I Implement this easily in Matlab?

You can use `imfilter` to apply the Sobel or Scharr filters, then `.*` to multiply/square the results pixelwise, then `imfilter` again to apply the gaussian smoothing kernel.

> How about in C++?

Any decent image processing library should contain functions for linear filters and pixel-wise multiplication. e.g. for the IPP, the functions would be called `ippiFilterRow/Column...`, `ippiMul...` and `ippiSqr...`

> Any comments regarding choice of smoothing kernel and differentiation operator?

I think the gaussian smoothing kernel is pretty standard. Sobel and Scharr are both common choices for the differentiation operator. Another good choice would be a gaussian derivative filter. Which one's best depends on your application: how noisy are your images? How sharp are the contrasts you're looking for? (If there's lots of noise, and the contrasts are sharp, a derivative filter with a larger aperture like the gaussian derivative might be better). How important is rotational symmetry?

> How do I normalize the Gaussian derivative?

The gaussian is: $\frac{1}{2 \pi  \sigma ^2}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}$

Deriving by x yields:

$\partial _x\left(\frac{1}{2 \pi  \sigma ^2}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}\right) = -\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} x}{2 \pi  \sigma ^4}$

So I think you should divide by `gd = -x.*g/(si^2);` because `sum(g)=2*pi*(si^2)`

Comment: Thanks for tipping me about the Gaussian derivative nikie! I want to go with this. I added some lines to my question regarding this. By IPP you mean Intel Integrated Performance Primitives?

Comment: @Andy Yes IPP is Intel Performance Primitives.