# How to calculate to structure tensor?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Structure Tensor is a matrix in form:

$S=\begin{pmatrix} W \ast I_x^2 & W \ast (I_xI_y)\\ W \ast (I_xI_y) & W \ast I_y^2 \end{pmatrix}$

where $W$ is a smoothing kernel (e.g a Gaussian kernel) and $I_x$ is gradient in the direction of $x$ and so on.

Therefore,size of structure tensor is $2N \times 2M$ (were $N$ is the image height and $M$ is its width). However it is supposed to be $2\times2$ matrix to decompose eigenvalues such that we obtain $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ as it is mentioned in many papers.

So, how to calculate $S$ matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171991/what-does-eigen-value-of-structure-tensor-matrix-denote/23172317#23172317) you have the definition slightly wrong. It's more like:

$$
S(\mathbf{u})=\begin{pmatrix} [W \ast I_x^2](\mathbf{u}) & [W \ast (I_xI_y)](\mathbf{u})\\
[W \ast (I_xI_y)](\mathbf{u}) & [W \ast I_y^2](\mathbf{u}) \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\mathbf{u} = (x,y)$ the location at which $S$ is evaluated.

In other words, the algorithm is to form $W \ast I_x^2$, $W \ast (I_xI_y)$, $W \ast (I_xI_y)$, and $W \ast I_y^2$ which are all $N\times M$ images, and then look at the appropriate pixel in each of them to form the $2\times 2$ matrix $S$.

Answer (score 0):

The $S$ matrix is finally of $2\times2$ the size of the initial image. Gathering it is a bigger image is somehow misleading. You effectively get a $2\times 2$ matrix **at each pixel** of the original image, by gathering values from the $4$ submatrices at corresponding locations.

Structure tensor provides local information. Do not forget to use smoothed directional derivatives as well when computing $I_x$ and $I_y$. You can for instance compute them with Difference of Gaussians (DoG) operators.
More discussion in  [How do I implement the Structure tensor (in Matlab)?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2963/how-do-i-implement-the-structure-tensor-in-matlab) or [Structure tensor tutorial](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sarsen/structureTensorTutorial/).

Comment: Should I calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for each pixel?

Comment: @Bhoke Indeed, orientation is local